# trigger existing event on appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get both blur and keypress(13) to do the same thing on an element that has been appended. An obvious use for trigger(), right? Not working. I'm hoping I'm just being stupid and missing something obvious.

```js
$(document).ready (function() {
  $("#btn").click (function() {
    $("#this-ul").append ("<li><input id='input1' type='text'></li><li><input type='text' id='input2'></li>");
    $("#input1").focus();
  });
  $("#this-ul").on ("blur", "#input1", function() {
    $("#input2").val ("blurred");
  });
  $("#this-ul").on ("keypress", "#input1", function (e) {
    if (e.which == 13) {
      // Want to trigger $("#this-ul").on ("blur"...) as above
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>

<button id="btn" type="button">Click</button>
<ul id="this-ul"></ul>
```

Comment: Use classes `.myClass` instead of id's in handler definitions. `$("#this-ul").on ("keypress", ".inputs", function (e) {...`

Comment: You're getting the error because at the time your handler is bound there is no element with id `#input1`. Use classes as @AlexKudryashev suggests and you should be in ok shape.

Comment: @Brian Driscoll: `input1` and `input2` are the content of the appended element.

Comment: @Teemu: I'm not sure it's a duplicate. I think it only it is a "how to use `.trigger` method".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $("#btn").click (function() {
        $("#this-ul").append ("<li><input id='input1' type='text'></li><li><input type='text' id='input2'></li>");
        $("#input1").focus();
    });
    $("#this-ul").on ("blur", "#input1", function() {
        $("#input2").val ("blurred");
    });
    $("#this-ul").on ("keypress", "#input1", function (e) {
        if (e.which == 13) {
            $(this).trigger("blur");
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle here : https://jsfiddle.net/2b10cyez/

On `blur` of input 1, input 2 gets the value "blurred".
And on [enter] keypress, the blur event is triggered.

Comment: I don't understant the downvote... Since the **Fiddle IS working** as the OP asked.

Comment: This will work! I knew it was something I'd just plain missed.

Comment: Maybe I should have said $(this) will work. :-)

Comment: `$(this).trigger("success");` is my current brain-spin... I try ! :-D